# Get coordinate point every x kilometers along the polyline

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have an array of coordinates that make up a polyline. Now i would like to get lat/lng point every 5 km from start point to end point on that polyline. Is there some function in Leaflet js for that or some other way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share the code you already have as a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: https://turfjs.org/docs/#along

Comment: There's also [leaflet-geometryutil's `interpolateOnLine`](https://makinacorpus.github.io/Leaflet.GeometryUtil/global.html#interpolateOnLine), though that takes a ratio rather than a distance, so you'll need to get the total distance length of your line and compare it to 5km to get the proper ratio to use.  Turfjs's method is more direct, but this is another option.

Comment: @SethLutske can you please explain a little more how to get proper ratio. So for example
my line lenght is 20km what ratio would i use to get coordinates every 5km.

Comment: I posted an answer explaining everything...I hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here's an explanation of how to use leaflet geometryutil (GeoUtil from here on out) to do what you want.

First, let's get the total length of your polyline.  You can do this using GeoUtil and a reduce function.

```js
const lengths = GeoUtil.accumulatedLengths(latlngs);
const totalLength = lengths.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

Assuming `latlngs` is an array of `L.LatLng` objects, `GeoUtil.accumulatedLengths` will return an array of distances between those latlngs.  Then we reduce that array down to the sum of its parts in the `reduce` statement.

Next, we figure out how many points you're going to have along your line based on the interval you want (5km), and the total distance:

```js
const interval = 5000; // 5km
const totalPoints = Math.floor(totalLength / interval);
```

So we will have `totalPoints` points along your line. Now we need to find out how far along the line each point is as a *ratio*:

```js
const ratios = [];
for (let i = 0; i <= totalPoints; i++) {
  const ratio = i / totalPoints;
  ratios.push(ratio);
}
```

So `ratios` will be an array of numbers between 0 and 1, with the same length as the number of points we expect to have on the line.  If this part confuses you, ask for more explanations in a comment.

Now we have that array of ratios, we can use it in `GeoUtil.interpolateOnLine`:

```js
const points = ratios.map((ratio) =>
  GeoUtil.interpolateOnLine(map, latlngs, ratio)
);

points.forEach((point) => {
  L.marker(point.latLng).addTo(map);
});
```

`points` is an array of `L.LatLng` points, at equal intervals along your line.  Which I believe is what you are looking to achieve.

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interpolated-points-tc5dn)

**Note: the use of Math.floor is crucial to get an integer value when calculating how many points along the line you'll have.  This may make it feel like we're "leaving off" the last point, but unless your total distance is an exact multiple of your interval distance, this is required to get the math to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set markers on the line you can use the library [leaflet-distance-marker](https://github.com/adoroszlai/leaflet-distance-markers).

```
var line = L.polyline(coords, {
    distanceMarkers: {offset: 5000 }
});
```

[Demo](http://adoroszlai.github.io/leaflet-distance-markers/)

Else take a look into the [code](https://github.com/adoroszlai/leaflet-distance-markers/blob/master/leaflet-distance-marker.js#L44-L76) and copy it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I looked into `distanceMarkers` function and the thing i don't get is what `L.GeometryUtil.accumulatedLengths(line)` does. Do you know by any chance.

Comment: It returns an array with the length between each point + length of points before. So if every coord is 2 km away the array would look like: [2,4,6,8,10] and 10 is the total length of the line